# Understanding Java singleton Design pattern

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

During reading the Spring Framework's documentation I came across the following:

> Spring’s concept of a singleton bean differs from the Singleton
>   pattern as defined in the Gang of Four (GoF) patterns book. The GoF
>   Singleton hard-codes the scope of an object such that one and only one
>   instance of a particular class is created ***per ClassLoader***. The scope
>   of the Spring singleton is best described as per container and per
>   bean.

I don't understand why per ClassLoader? Why don;t per the entire application or in the Context they are considered to be the same things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the traditional singleton, you have a static variable in the Singleton class to keep the single instance. However since you can load the same class using multiple `ClassLoaders`, those will have their own static variables and are free to create their own instance.

In most cases this is not a problem anyway.

Comment: How is it ever possible to load the same class twice by the different class loaders? Does it make a sense?

Comment: It's possible by creating a `ClassLoader` (such as `URLClassLoader`), loading a class with it, then repeating the same with another `ClassLoader`. It makes a lot of sense, although that's quite a broad subject to go into here.